# can we create custom exception extending class other than Exception and Runtimeexception?

Tags: java, exception

can we create custom exception extending class other than `Exception` and  `RuntimeException`?

Comment: You can try it for yourself and find out. For the record, exceptions are also classes and they can be extended if not final.

Comment: Thanks but can any subclass of Exception or Runtimeexception is suitable for writing Custom Exception? or it might face problems in catching exceptions in later scenarios?

Comment: Both can be used to create custom Exceptions. The decision depends on whether you want your exception to be checked (Exception) or unchecked (RuntimeException). Find some resources here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `Error` or directly `Throwable`

Comment: Thanks but   can any subclass of Exception or Runtimeexception is suitable for writing Custom Exception?

Comment: @shekharsuman could you elaborate that? It seems like an answer to me, it says he can do what he wants with 2 examples

Comment: @CarlosRodriguez - Sorry, I incorrectly flagged it as "not being an answer". I apologise for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend any class that is not final. Exceptions are no exceptions.

Comment: can any subclass of Exception or Runtimeexception is suitable for writing Custom Exception? or it might face problems in catching exceptions in later scenarios?

Comment: I suggest you brush up on what the difference between checked and unchecked exception is (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011749/checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java). Because yes, sub-classing Exception and RuntimeException will have an impact on how you write your code (more specifically, whether you need to catch your exception, declare it or do nothing in particular)