# Convert a String in Clob

Tags: java, spring, string, clob

I have a string "stringData" and I want to convert it in a Clob, can you help me?

I have tried:

```
Clob clob = new SerialClob(stringData.toCharArray());
```

but it gives error.

Comment: And what error does it give?

Comment: Unhandled exception type SQLException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue of `Unhandled Exception` isn't directly an issue with the `.toCharArray()` and `SerialClob`. Rather, the issue is that Checked Exceptions must either be caught or declared as part of the method.

So (Example 1):

```
try {
  ...
  Clob clob = new SerialClob(stringData.toCharArray());
  ...
}
catch (SQLException e) {
  // do handle better than this, however
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or (Example 2):

```
/**
   @throws SQLException If there is an issue with creating the data, or 
                        inserting into the DB
*/
private void storeData(StringData stringData) throws SQLException
{
  ...
  Clob clob = new SerialClob(stringData.toCharArray());
  ...
 }
```

Of course, with the latter, some other method will need to catch the SQLException.

Essentially, an `SQLException` is a CheckedException. From the [JLS 11.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2)

> The Java programming language requires that a program contains handlers for checked exceptions which can result from execution of a method or constructor. For each checked exception which is a possible result, the throws clause for the method (§8.4.6) or constructor (§8.8.5) must mention the class of that exception or one of the superclasses of the class of that exception (§11.2.3).

So, either the `SQLException` must be caught (example 1), or added to the `throws` clause for the method (example 2).

The reason you received the compile time issue is found in 
[JLS, 11.2.3 Exception Checking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html):

> It is a compile-time error if a method or constructor body can throw some exception class E when E is a checked exception class and E is not a subclass of some class declared in the throws clause of the method or constructor.

There is also discussion in the accepted answer to [this question about Checked vs. Unchecked Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011749/checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java)