# Java - BackingStoreException()

Tags: java, exception

I'm a little curious to this exception when being thrown.

```
  public void addDailyUVReport(DailyUVReport report)
{
        counter++;
        if (counter > CAPACITY)
          throw new BackingStoreException("Called too many times");
}
```

How come that doesn't work? But... this does.

```
 public void addDailyUVReport(DailyUVReport report) throws BackingStoreException
  {
    counter++;
    if (counter > CAPACITY)
      throw new BackingStoreException("Called too many times");
  }
```

I know when you throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException() you do not need the throw clause? and can just create a new one without having the clause with the method. Would it have to do with it being void?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions which extend `RuntimeException` are called `unchecked` and do not need to be declared in the method signature.

See here for more: [Difference between Unchecked exception or runtime exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699580/difference-between-unchecked-exception-or-runtime-exception)

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. Actually just learned this in class today but he didn't really go over it. Just briefly explained it to us to get more familiar for later. Beginner programmer here o.o