# unhandled exception type MessagingException when adding setFrom in javamail

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-mail

```
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xyz@example.com"));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("abcd@example.com"));
```

Getting error in last two lines that `unhandled exception type MessagingException`.

Eclipse suggests me to cover them with a try catch block.But when i tried to search in internet they are using these two statement without any try catch block. so i think i am doing something wrong. 
how to solve this?

Comment: [Lessons: Exceptions (The Java™ Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: Could you please check in the internet that they may be throws MessagingException instead of covering try catch block.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences between Runtime/Checked/Unchecked/Error/Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162760/differences-between-runtime-checked-unchecked-error-exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to possibilities to solve it.

1. Add a try-catch- block arround your code:

   try {
       MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
       msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xyz@example.com"));
       msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("abcd@example.com"));

   } catch (MessagingException me){
     // do something
   }
2. Add `throws MessagingException` to the method signature:

   public void mymethod throws MessagingException {
       MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
       msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xyz@example.com"));
       msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("abcd@example.com"));
   }