# Customized Exception is checked or unchecked Exception?

Tags: java, exception, unchecked-exception

Whether the Customized Exception is Checked or Unchecked Exception? How?

Comment: If it inherits from `RuntimeException` it is unchecked. Otherwise it is checked.

Comment: Under Exception class, comes both RunTimeException (Unchecked) and other Checked Exceptions. So how could we be so sure that our customized exception is checked if it inherits Exception class?

Comment: **Check whether it inherits from RuntimeException**

Answer (score 2):

If you do like this:

```
public class CustomException extends Exception
```

then your CustomException is checked exception

If you do like this:

```
public class CustomException extends RuntimeException
```

then your CustomException is unchecked exception

Comment: Under Exception class, comes both RunTimeException (Unchecked) and other Checked Exceptions. So how could we be so sure that our customized exception is checked if it inherits Exception class?

Comment: It is handled by the compiler. It check for hierarchy, basically the checked exception are created because they can occur at many points in the program and recovery from them is difficult or impossible and developer can handle them in code.

Answer (score 0):

If an exception inherits from [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) then it is unchecked. Otherwise it is checked.

Comment: If it just inherits Exception class?

Comment: If it just inherits from `Exception`, then it's checked.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what it inherits. If your custom exception is a subclass of `RuntimeException` then it is **unchecked** exception.

And if your custom exception extends `Exception` class then it is **checked** exception.

See the [Differences between Runtime/Checked/Unchecked/Error/Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162760/differences-between-runtime-checked-unchecked-error-exception/27763869#27763869) for more details

Answer (score 0):

depends on inheritance. if it inherits from RuntimeException it is unchecked. Otherwise it is checked