# java, throwing unchecked exception by making an object of Throwable

Tags: java, exception, throw, throwable

what is the difference between the following two codes? one of them is working fine while other is giving a compilation error.

**compilation problem in code 1**

```
class XYZ
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Throwable obj = new ArithmeticException("this is an error");    
        throw obj;
    }
}
```

**ERROR -**

```
XYZ.java:7: error: unreported exception Throwable; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                throw obj;
                ^
1 error
error: compilation failed
```

**Successful execution in code 2**

```
class XYZ
{
    public static void main(String[] args) //throws InterruptedException
    {
        throw new ArithmeticException("this is an error");
    }
}
```

**output**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: this is an error
        at XYZ.main(XYZ.java:6)
```

As we can see both the codes are identical but the one at the top is giving a compilation error whereas the second code is working without a flaw.

I wanna know

- why this is so?
- How can I make my first code work fine?

Comment: `Throwable` is checked exception and `ArithmeticException` is unchecked exception

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162760/differences-between-runtime-checked-unchecked-error-exception

Comment: @Deadpool thanks bruh, I totally forgot about the checked and unchecked exceptions.